# Java regex generate pattern

Tags: java, regex

I try to generate my `Pattern`, to be able to set/add/edit it through `JTextfield` in UI
for variant2 it works OK, but if I try to add more then one pattern (variant1) it stops to work.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is relevant part of code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestSomeStaff {

String getPattern(String s) {
    String p = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
            p += "\\" + "w";
        } else if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            p += "\\" + "d";
        } else {
            p += s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return p;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String code1 = "11XXX08_XX000XX__XX11";
    String code2 = "11XXX08_XX000X__XX11";
    TestSomeStaff t = new TestSomeStaff();

    // String p="("+t.getPattern(code1) + ") | ("+t.getPattern(code2)+")";
    // //variant1
    String p = t.getPattern(code1); // variant 2
    System.out.println(t.getPattern(code1));
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(p);

    Matcher m = pat.matcher(code1);
    System.out.println("pattern:" + m.pattern());

    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
}
```

var1 output:

```
\d\d\w\w\w\d\d_\w\w\d\d\d\w\w__\w\w\d\d
pattern:(\d\d\w\w\w\d\d_\w\w\d\d\d\w\w__\w\w\d\d) | (\d\d\w\w\w\d\d_\w\w\d\d\d\w__\w\w\d\d)
```

var2 output:

```
\d\d\w\w\w\d\d_\w\w\d\d\d\w\w__\w\w\d\d
pattern:\d\d\w\w\w\d\d_\w\w\d\d\d\w\w__\w\w\d\d
11XXX08_XX000XX__XX11
```

Comment: Although it is not very clear what are you going to do, in order to match pattern you should remove spaces in variant 1: ")|("

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces in the `variant1` pattern are important. If you remove the space then the variant will work.

Comment: **Everything** in a Regular Expression (Pattern) is means something.